# Apache Reverse Proxy Mac OS Server

Tags: reverse-proxy

So aside from my work as a java dev, I've been trying to improve my infrastructure skills. This has lead me to setting up MacOs server at home and starting to run some services from home. At present I have three main services I'd like to access externally, with security, but I only have one working outside my network.

I'll try and be as verbose as possible, but let me know if there is any more information required.

The three services are: SVN, GIT and Jenkins

My server is running locally at 10.0.1.11, from within my network I can access the Jenkins instance running at port 8080, this can also be accessed at xyz.ddns.net:8080. SVN is set up via webdav and can be accessed at xyz.ddns.net/svn. However I'm having issues setting up my git to be externally accessible, and Jenkins to be accessible at a certain address.

I'd like to access these three services at 
xyz.ddns.net/svn - which works with basic authentication
xyz.ddns.net/jenkins - which doesn't work at all, but I can get to from port 8080
xyz.ddns.net/git - which I can't reach at all from outside

My git server is based on the bitnami gitlab image and is locally on 10.0.1.35.

Below is my httpd file, which for the most part is the default stuff generated by MacOS Server. All the internal addresses work fine, I'd just like to get them accessible externally ideally all with basic authentication.

Many thanks for any tips or links, I've been looking at this for days and I've not progressed at all.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:34580>
    ServerName default
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default"
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php default.html
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/access_log" combinedvhost
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/error_log"

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
            SSLEngine Off
            SSLCipherSuite "HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES"
            SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
            SSLProxyEngine Off
            SSLProxyProtocol -all +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
            SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
            SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_secure_transport.c>
            MSTEngine Off
            MSTCipherSuite HIGH, MEDIUM
            MSTProtocolRange TLSv1.2 TLSv1.2
            MSTProxyEngine On
            MSTProxyProtocolRange TLSv1.2 TLSv1.2
    </IfModule>
    <Directory "/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default">
            Options All -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes +MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            <IfModule mod_dav.c>
                    DAV Off
            </IfModule>
            <IfDefine !WEBSERVICE_ON>
                    Require all denied
                    ErrorDocument 403 /customerror/websitesoff403.html
            </IfDefine>
    </Directory>



    ProxyPass /svn/projects http://www.server.com/svn/projects/
    ProxyPassReverse /svn/projects http://www.server.com/svn/projects/


    ProxyPass /jenkins/ http://www.server.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /jenkins/ http:/www.server.com:8080/

    ProxyPass /git/ https://10.0.1.35/
    ProxyPassReverse /git/ https://10.0.1.35/


    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(^localhost|^127.0.0.1|^::1)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/netboot/ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `trying to improve my infrastructure skills` and `MacOS server` don't belong in the same sentence (anymore). If you want to learn, use a better foundation.

Comment: @Sven Would you recommend me reposting to Super User? I'm sorry you feel that MacOs Server and infrastructure don't belong together anymore